# Loop in dataPoints

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I'm trying to loop inside the dataPoints of a doughnut chart. I have a dynamic array of values(string) in PHP but this array changes often. I'm displaying in dataPoints my php variables in other graphs but for this doughnut chart I'm trying to loop in dataPoints so it sets the {y} and the name automatically as well.

```
data: [{
        type: "doughnut",
        innerRadius: 60,
        showInLegend: true,
        toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: {y}",
        indexLabel: "{name} - {y}",
        indexLabelFontSize: 14,
        dataPoints: dps
/*[
                { y: <?echo $Count_Upcoming;?>, name: "Up coming", color: "#215C89" },
                { y: <?echo $Count_Planned;?>,  name: "Scheduled", color: "#3984BD" },
                { y: <?echo $Count_Review;?>,  name: "In Review", color: "#46A4EB" },
                { y: <?echo $Count_Trouble;?>,  name: "Trouble", color: "#DC5151" },
                { y: <?echo $Count_Maint;?>,  name: "UG Maintenance", color: "#659FC8" },
                { y: <?echo $Count_CUST;?>, name: "Services", color: "#A0B2BF" }
            ]*/
}]
```

and outside this I'm trying to do this:

```
<?for($i = 0; $i < $COUNT_TYPE; $i++){?>

    dps.push({y: <?echo $val[$i];?> }, name: <?echo $key[$i];?>)
<?}?>
```

my php array:

```
                         $NEW_TYPEOFWORK = array_count_values($TW);
                         foreach($NEW_TYPEOFWORK as $key[]=>$val[]){}
                         $COUNT_TYPE = count($NEW_TYPEOFWORK);
```

How can this be done? or if there is any other ways to loop for dataPoints for php variables inside the javascript chart.

Comment: what is your issue? You ask 'How can this be done?', but explain how you do this - my god feeling is you mix server and client programming - however since I do not understand your issue I could be wrong on this

Comment: There is no issue. I'm trying to create as much sections in the doughnut as with the size of the categories of the array which is in PHP. The only way to do that is with a for loop for sure. For example, I have an array that counts as this: Array ( [Overload] => 42  [Reliability] => 1024 [Relocation] => 20 [NRUC] => 7 [Storm] => 589). There is 5 categories so the doughnut should have 5 sections but this array may have more categories in the future so I need that to be automatically added to the doughnut chart. How that can be done using a for loop in canvasJS dataPoints.

Answer (score 0):

did not understand where in your php array is the color - however I would do the php ouput loop like this:

```
<?
  foreach($NEW_TYPEOFWORK as $key=>$val) echo("{y:".$val.";name:'".$key."';color:'#777777'");
?>
```

Comment: The idea is right. I put it as this in the CanvasJs but still not working: data: [{
  type: "doughnut",
  innerRadius: 60,
  showInLegend: true,
  toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: {y}",
  indexLabel: "{name} - {y}",
  indexLabelFontSize: 14,
  dataPoints: [
  <?foreach($NEW_TYPEOFWORK as $key=>$val) {echo("{y:".$val.", name:'".$key."',color:'#777777'}");}

?>]}] any suggestions here!?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this:
php: setting the array as this:

```
foreach($NEW_TYPEOFWORK as $key=>$val){$datapoint[] = array("y"=> $val, "name"=> $key); }
```

in CanvasJS:

```
data: [{
        type: "doughnut",
        innerRadius: 60,
        showInLegend: true,
        toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: {y}",
        indexLabel: "{name} - {y}",
        indexLabelFontSize: 14,
        dataPoints: <?echo json_encode($datapoint, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>

    }]
```

Comment: not sure, what's the benefit in writting this to an array of 'php-records' and then employing an encoding routine over directly writing the output - performance wise I try to avoid such constructs in my programming - anyway, good you have got a solution

Comment: one last hint for general use of stackoverflow: maybe you can be a bit more precise next time what is really your issue - I did lots of assumptions to answer your question (e.g. I assumed that dps.push in your code snippets is not important while not knowing that you are looking into writing an intermediate solution into an array) - likewise 'still not working' in your comment would be nice to be explained (error xyz, output xyz which is not needed, because...)